# QGIS/QField external sensor set up

Tags: qgis, qfield

Last version of QGIS (3.34.2) introduced the possibility to connect external sensors to collect sensor data into a QGIS project.
Adding a new sensors you are asked to define:

- Sensor name
- Sensor type (TCP socket sensor, UDP socket sensor, serial port sensor)
- Host name (a domain string or IP address)
- Port

It is not clear to me how to know the right parameters to be set and what they actually mean.
I am kind of new into connecting external sensors in general and about connection protocols in general.

QGIS documentation I found about it is one:https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/qgis_configuration.html#sensors-properties  at section 9.3.14

I would like to understand how to connect a bluetooth sensor such as a temperature sensor, or a distance sensor, to collect measured data into a field of a point layer using QField.

[image: this is the window how it appears in QGIS project properties]

Answer (score 1):

By the looks of it, the Sensors is meant to be used over internet protocols (TCP/UDP). This [doesn't work directly with Bluetooth](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1137617/14681457), so you would need something extra for it to work and without specifics, I cannot answer that question.

For the other part: "What do these things mean?", here is some explanation:

- **name**: for yourself, to distinguish it from other sensors
- **Type**: gives three options

  - TCP socket. TCP is an internet protocol that ensures proper data transfer. for a sensor that does not so many measurements where it is important to receive all of them.
  - UDP socket: UDP is also an internet protocol, where the sensor just spams the network with data, hoping it will arrive.
  - Serial: this is for binary transfer, specified in baud. For a cable into your computer e.g. [here](https://forum.arduino.cc/t/usb-serial-baud-rates-or-other-faster-usb-communication-methods/128996)
- Host name: If the sensor is indeed an internet sensor, your computer can find it (and open a connection) by giving its IP number.
- Port: Connections between different internet nodes happens on different ports. make sure these match between your sensor and the computer, otherwise, they cannot communicate. There are standard ports for different protocols, but you could [do whatever you want on your local network](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10477099/14681457).

I wouldn't know how to get it to work with bluetooth, but here's [some tutorials](https://randomnerdtutorials.com/esp32-guides-sensors-modules/) for ESPs with different environment sensors. ESPs have WiFi by default.

Happy tinkering!